# two related sums and the situation that make them unequal

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_1,z_2\cdots,z_n$ be any nonzero complex numbers with non-unit moduli,  and let $m<\min\{|z_1|,|z_2|\cdots,|z_n|\}\leq 1.$ Then I think for any real value of $\theta,$
$$m^n \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-z_k}\right|\neq \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{z_k}{e^{i\theta}-z_k}\right|.$$ The result is true when $n=1.$ The result  is obivious if $m=0.$ Whether induction principle help in this case? or any other techniques available? Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to speak of a minimum of complex numbers, or to say that they're less than/greater than another complex number... unlike real numbers, there is no "less than" or "greater than" for complex numbers, they do not have a total order unlike real numbers.

Comment: There were typos. I apologize. Now corrected.